# "No appropriate method" error generated when calling new function using class-defined object

Tags: oop, class, function, matlab, object

I defined a class called "FilterCriteria" which has a bunch of function .m files (getAMask, getBMask, etc.) associated with it. When I create the FilterCriteria object and call the functions using it, I don't have any problems. However, recently I added another function (which, on a side note, is almost identical to another function that still works), and Matlab returns the error, "No appropriate method, property, or field getHMask for class FilterCriteria."

I've searched online for this problem, but I can't find anything. The file getHMask.m is definitely in the correct folder, so I don't understand why Matlab seems to have such a problem finding it.

Here's getHMask.m's header:

```
function mask = getHMask(object, quadrant, channel)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the function declarations in your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1)  A mistake I make sometimes is not saving the file with the correct name.  Make sure capital letters are in the right places etc!

2) Another layer of error checking here...  You can call `methods('object here')` [(see here)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/api/methods.html) and make sure it lists the method (function) that you are trying to add to it.  If it doesn't show up here you should check into the implementation of the method and make sure it's correctly being added to the class you're using for your object.

Comment: Thanks, Ben! In my particular case, all I had to do was restart Matlab... then for some reason it recognized the .m file. Just for kicks, I tried your number 2 and it was a great way to debug (in fact, I found a different method was being added to the wrong class!).

Comment: Upvote for the first mistake! :-) (came here to search for the same issue and the mistake I did was giving wrong names!)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem that's kind of suggested by Ben's bullet #2 and it was driving me crazy. Turns out MatLab wasn't loading the latest version of my class's m-file. I vaguely remembered it gave me a warning earlier about that, because there were old instances of the class in the workspace and to keep from invalidating them it said it wouldn't update the class until I cleared the workspace...

So if that's the problem, restarting MatLab will work, or you can just enter `>> clear`

Comment: Let's say that using 'clear' every time this error occurs wastes a huge amount of time (data need to be reloaded, reprocessed, etc etc). Is there any other solution to force Matlab to 'reload' the source code you just saved? Why is is so hard to make it reload and recompile your code: it's the only environment where this happens.

Comment: Antonio, the problem is that if you redefine a class (e.g., add or remove a property from it), the existing objects that were created by the old version of the class will conflict with the new version of the class. You'd have to have a way to surgically recreate only the affected objects using the new class if you wanted to avoid clearing the entire workspace.

Comment: I have only one object (assigned to a single variable) used to test the class: a new istance of the class is assigned to that variable for every update of the class. There are no 'old' objects, just one that should - theoretically - be created and initialized whenever I run that specific code. Frankly, I cannot understand why it does not work. Clearing the variable referencing that object does not work. The only way I have found is to issue a `clear` command with the classname: the problem seems to be related to an outdated 'compiled' class and not to outdated objects.

Comment: @AntonioSesto, interesting, perhaps that issue deserves its own question on SO to bring it to the attention of whoever in the community may know of an alternative to issuing `clear`.

Comment: Try `clear classes`, that should clear the cache for classes without clearing variables in order to reimport class definitions. 
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/4886-update-class-without-restarting-matlab